# AWS Glue - using Crawlers or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

For a job to run on a data from an S3 bucket in parquet format, there are two ways:

1. Create a crawler to create a schema table, use `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(dbname, tablename)` to form the dynamic frame inside a Glue job.
2. Read directly from S3 using `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options("s3", {"paths": [full_s3_path] }, format="parquet")`

Since my data scheme will NOT change in time, are there any advantages (performance-wise or else) to use a Crawler? Why do I need a Crawler in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is not partitioned or you don't want to use [predicate-pushdown](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/) feature then you don't need to run a Crawler.

However, if it is partitioned and you want to be able to load data partially with predicate-pushdown then new partitions should be registered in Data Catalog and Crawler is one of the easiest ways to do that (there are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067709/aws-glue-crawlers-and-large-tables-stored-in-s3/53069505#53069505) though)